# Access property from settings.gradle in Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, settings, build.gradle

I am in the process of building a custom Gradle plugin using [the following guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html). I want to define a property in the `settings.gradle` file and read it in the plugin class, but every attempt failed so far.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Could not find property 'MyProperty' on root Project 'MyProject'
```

Here is my `settings.gradle` file:

```
gradle.ext.MyProperty = "The Value"
```

and here is the file containing my plugin:

```
package myplugin.gradle

import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Plugin

class FirstPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('myTask') << {
            def instance = project.MyProperty
            println "VALUE : " + instance
        }
    }
}
```

I can access `MyProperty` if I put `project.ext.set("MyProperty", "Property Value")` in `build.gradle`, but I can't find a way to set it in the `settings.gradle` file.

I guess one way to fix this issue would be to read the content of `settings.gradle` in `build.gradle` and send it to the plugin using `project.ext.set(...)`, but is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, the way to go (which is better anyways) is to use an extension object. This extension object allows to send data from the `build.gradle` file to the plugin. The `build.gradle` file reads the content of the variable in the `settings.gradle` file and puts it in the extension object.

In the file containing the plugin:

```
package myplugin.gradle

import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Plugin

class MyExtension {
    String myProperty
}

class FirstPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create('myExtensionName', MyExtension)
        project.task('myTask') << {
            def instance = project.myExtensionName.myProperty
            println "VALUE : " + instance
        }
    }
}
```

In the `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'myPluginName'
...

myExtensionName {
    myProperty = gradle.ext.myPropertyInSettings
}
```

And finally, in the `settings.gradle` file :

```
gradle.ext.myPropertyInSettings = "The Value"
```

Also, I recommend [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/gradle-custom-plugin.html) tutorial instead of the one provided by Gradle.

Answer (score -1):

I have a gradle project where a property set in `settings.gradle` is accessed from 3 places:

- settings.gradle itself
- build.gradle (including `subprojects {}` )
- a gradle plugin in ./buildSrc

#### Accessing from `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle`:

`gradle.ext.MY_PROPERTY_NAME`

#### Accessing from a `gradle plugin`'s apply() method:

(plugin is applied from `subprojects {}` closure)

`project.rootProject.gradle.ext.MY_PROPERTY_NAME`

This seems to work fine in Gradle 4.7 and Gradle 5.2